# In JAVA How to send byte[] data to downloadable file?

Tags: java, servlets, arrays, outputstream

I am working on a Dynamic Work Project in Eclipse using JAVA HttpServlets.

I have some data in byte[] format which I am getting through some API call. I am able to store this in a new file but what I want is that it should be available for the user to download in different formats like csv, xls, pdf.

I referred to some links. I am using saveReportToLocalMachine method for saving it
which is working fine.
But if I use displayReportToUser for the same byte[] data, it creates a downlaodable file but that file shows damaged error.

```
public static void saveReportToLocalMachine(byte[] data, String fileLocation,
        String filename) throws IOException {

    File file = new File(fileLocation, filename);
    FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fstream.write(data);
    fstream.close();
}
```

Now below is the method to make the file downloadable.

```
private void displayReportToUser(byte[] byteData, String outputType,  
 HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=temp.pdf");

    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    out.write(byteData);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

But this is not working for me.
Can someone please guide and explain?
Please point out errors

Comment: you should post your answer or atleast accept the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

```
while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}
```

You're ignoring the count. The correc copy loop in Java is as follows:

```
int count;
while((count = in.read(outputByte)) > 0)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, count);
}
```

You don't need to flush `out` before closing.

But as you have the data as a `byte[],` you only need to call `out.write(data).` There's no need for the `ByteArrayInputStream,` or the loop, at all.

Comment: I tried it but not working.. it downloads the file but shows it as damaged. 
But if I output the byte[] data in a new file it works fine, so the problem is not with data.

Comment: Maybe you didn't copy the code accurately. See also my edit. I don't know what the `ByteArrayInputStream` is even doing there. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for replying promptly, could you please point out errors in my code? I have improved my question

Comment: Resolved how? Please post your solution here as a courtesy to past and future readers.